# Creating a bookmark results in "semaphore_wait_trap" in iOS 11.2+

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to create a bookmark. In iOS 11.0.3 the following code works fine **when using a physical device**. In iOS 11.2+ (11.2.2 for example) the code freezes the app. Closing the app and reopening creates a crash.

Can anyone else reproduce this? Is there something wrong with the creation of a bookmark that changed in 11.2?

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath)

print("Bookmarking: \(String(describing: url))")

do {
    _ = try url.bookmarkData(options: .suitableForBookmarkFile, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
} catch {
    print("Error converting URL to bookmark: \(String(describing: error))")
}

print("Done")
```

If you run against a simulator the console shows this error, but does not freeze the app. Note that the catch statement does not actually catch an error:

```
[ERROR] Could not create a bookmark: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099
"The connection from pid 25777 was invalidated." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 25777 was invalidated.}
```

Crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 46FC141C-D120-4FF4-8003-97FD46A7712C
CrashReporter Key:   8cd5f36267c3530a35ff7e3c13b2dde873b3c11d
Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
Process:             BookmarkDataTestSwift [441]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/BookmarkDataTestSwift
Identifier:          jonathan.BookmarkDataTestSwift
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           jonathan.BookmarkDataTestSwift [642]


Date/Time:           2018-01-09 10:52:34.7368 -0600
Launch Time:         2018-01-09 10:52:14.6406 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.2 (15C202)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: jonathan.BookmarkDataTestSwift exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.96 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 11.340 (user 11.340, system 0.000), 38% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.001, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018271b5a4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001825a8f04 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001825a9e58 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 196
3   CoreServicesInternal              0x00000001a49bad1c createBookmarkWithURLAtDepth+ 19740 (__CFAllocator const*, __CFURL const*, unsigned long, __CFURL const*, __CFArray const*, BookmarkMutableData&, unsigned int, bool, __CFError**) + 3836
4   CoreServicesInternal              0x00000001a49b9ddc _CFURLCreateBookmarkData + 244
5   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182c5f934 -[NSURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:] + 244
6   libswiftFoundation.dylib          0x000000010153f970 0x101498000 + 686448
7   BookmarkDataTestSwift             0x0000000100c4bdd8 0x100c44000 + 32216
8   BookmarkDataTestSwift             0x0000000100c4c1d4 0x100c44000 + 33236
9   UIKit                             0x000000018c1e0ae8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
10  UIKit                             0x000000018c1e06c0 -[UIViewController view] + 28
11  UIKit                             0x000000018c1e728c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 136
12  UIKit                             0x000000018c1e44ec -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
13  UIKit                             0x000000018c2533a0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
14  UIKit                             0x000000018c440d10 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3620
15  UIKit                             0x000000018c445aa8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1712
16  UIKit                             0x000000018c6e12d4 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
17  UIKit                             0x000000018c9b912c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
18  UIKit                             0x000000018c6e0f38 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
19  UIKit                             0x000000018c6e1798 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 732
20  UIKit                             0x000000018ce667d0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
21  UIKit                             0x000000018ce66674 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
22  UIKit                             0x000000018cbd42dc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
23  UIKit                             0x000000018cd6d3dc _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
24  UIKit                             0x000000018cbd418c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
25  UIKit                             0x000000018c9b878c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
26  UIKit                             0x000000018c4441ec -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
27  UIKit                             0x000000018c859de8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
28  FrontBoardServices                0x00000001852ee1f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
29  FrontBoardServices                0x00000001852f6af8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
30  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001825a6a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
31  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001825ae200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
32  FrontBoardServices                0x00000001853227f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
33  FrontBoardServices                0x000000018532249c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
34  FrontBoardServices                0x0000000185322a38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
35  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182bd297c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
36  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182bd28fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
37  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182bd2184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
38  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182bcfd5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
39  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182aefe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
40  GraphicsServices                  0x000000018499cf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
41  UIKit                             0x000000018c24467c UIApplicationMain + 236
42  BookmarkDataTestSwift             0x0000000100c4dbe8 0x100c44000 + 39912
43  libdyld.dylib                     0x000000018260c56c start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018271b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018271b3e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182bd2308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182bcfed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000182aefe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                        0x0000000183525594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                        0x00000001835449ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                             0x000000018cdae7b8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                        0x00000001836270f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00000001828502b4 _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182850180 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018284eb74 thread_start + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018284eb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018284eb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x000000000000000e   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000000000019
x4: 0x0000000000000015   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000080
x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x00000001825d8d08  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
x12: 0x00000000000012f5  x13: 0x00000000000012f5  x14: 0x0000000008000200  x15: 0x00000000000012f5
x16: 0xffffffffffffffdc  x17: 0x0000000181e8f0e0  x18: 0xfffffff01f89925c  x19: 0x00000001c4094998
x20: 0xffffffffffffffff  x21: 0x00000001c409499c  x22: 0x0000000000000009  x23: 0x0000000000000001
x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000001c80a4ec0  x26: 0x00000001c80a4ec0  x27: 0x000000016f1b9140
x28: 0x0000000000000400   fp: 0x000000016f1b8b70   lr: 0x00000001825a8f04
sp: 0x000000016f1b8b60   pc: 0x000000018271b5a4 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x100c44000 - 0x100c4ffff BookmarkDataTestSwift arm64  <815c073394e330d9889e6eaf097f2cff> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/BookmarkDataTestSwift
0x100c60000 - 0x100c67fff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib arm64  <bfe40b3dfe1837bbb5009f381025e07f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
0x100c70000 - 0x100c7ffff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <dc3bbfe65d4f3329b2754894140ba397> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100c9c000 - 0x100ca3fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <bd87645763bb3d4a91ea01ddb74d22bd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x100cac000 - 0x100cb3fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <0a2b3149c0c834fb8e0dade27625a6a2> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x100cc8000 - 0x100d07fff dyld arm64  <477a8a1f098b3a80860d656a3f4918ea> /usr/lib/dyld
0x100d64000 - 0x1010dffff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <9399792d76de34748b4496d5d3015eb7> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x101440000 - 0x10145ffff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <9af40a87c38a3111afd1c247ea11f6a0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x101498000 - 0x1015effff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <7a6c628ec0373baa99a47b65bf23f9ea> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x101744000 - 0x10174bfff libswiftMetal.dylib arm64  <20ec95e3b8f43324bacb478bc6d7c2bd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
0x101758000 - 0x10175ffff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <4455217fc1a030e6a3947ca00c8008b9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x10176c000 - 0x101773fff libswiftQuartzCore.dylib arm64  <a4ca2c4ae9533a43a2cebc7e6d9d59e6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
0x10177c000 - 0x1017abfff libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib arm64  <3de77c3c89aa3fb09f2b7eb47fffba32> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
0x1017fc000 - 0x101807fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <c642d69442c33f92ae9321cb863d89f0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x10181c000 - 0x101823fff libswiftos.dylib arm64  <0ec3ab9ad4ce3b63a2af8872c7268dd2> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7650BEEA-A5E6-4BE9-AFE8-6F133F56ECBD/BookmarkDataTestSwift.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
0x101e84000 - 0x101e87fff CloudDocsFileProvider arm64  <f489ecbe13c83c739839ee594f075258> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/CloudDocsFileProvider.bundle/CloudDocsFileProvider
0x101e90000 - 0x101e93fff FileProviderOverride arm64  <7e8c2795afe233f2aa88445006458919> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FileProviderOverride.bundle/FileProviderOverride
0x181de9000 - 0x181deafff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <f1a8dae6cdac3bdeb67f9a56e4acb0d0> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x181deb000 - 0x181e44fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <aee157a049663aa88c4e928768cfd553> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x181e45000 - 0x181e65fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <b4f54419327f3bfea747549b84dad328> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x181e68000 - 0x182523fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <3a9d464322eb3285bc88fabf7cec20ed> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x182524000 - 0x182528fff libcache.dylib arm64  <5d31b020cbde3110981e6a8213297535> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x182529000 - 0x182534fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <5fcc43ca8cd9305091129711db270b8c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x182535000 - 0x182538fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <49e30d90aab53f8a99c9109db350ae39> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x182539000 - 0x182540fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <bc50a65225833e458ae22db52300bf10> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x182541000 - 0x1825a4fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <1647a3e06adc30b3b8f8298f897d6e87> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1825a5000 - 0x18260afff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <25e5e6ee10093937b122c4b509716294> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x18260b000 - 0x182625fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <aa89b903caf232bebaea4294ee62a6d2> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x182626000 - 0x182626fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <ca90373a022d3c38ac7ecd736c13bf9b> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x182627000 - 0x18262cfff libmacho.dylib arm64  <5cf371e4795437008e8ba71f7c18c3e0> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x18262d000 - 0x18262efff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <1f6279ea185b39ebab0412f03836952f> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18262f000 - 0x182646fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <dd425157f17d3c428245da87b0d36205> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x182647000 - 0x182647fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <93403bb53b293e748a97895ea5d99def> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x182648000 - 0x1826c5fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <400d9d205a453ab49971ab4bebbff01c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1826c6000 - 0x1826cafff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <1d864850ea2a32d6bb44b37cff02883c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x1826cb000 - 0x1826d0fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <fc551cabe5a334c1b09a49278900e46a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1826d1000 - 0x1826d2fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <367354d549a434efb82345e4010ae363> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x1826d3000 - 0x1826d4fff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <74d54bc023a2320a9d93943806b0c19e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1826d5000 - 0x1826dbfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <5c8c5aaa95393d4e8492379ff9efb960> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1826dc000 - 0x182719fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <a844d2a933a93a0ea78b2aa73be718ea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x18271a000 - 0x182742fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <1eb83b93d8e5382fa3692c4db5c8425e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x182743000 - 0x182770fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <fec251da685c39678cddf31fc925050a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x182771000 - 0x18278bfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <4867a62768f93413a9e9da35906b4624> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x18278c000 - 0x18282cfff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <27058056b60a3c5b9f7dd945f07ced58> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x18282d000 - 0x182838fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <26f9a6394d763402add762982498e16d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x182839000 - 0x182843fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <f4a564bb65e13f7fa40a7b3e7b400e16> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x182844000 - 0x18284dfff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <5bdfc85463ac3da5976bdb230cc9904e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x18284e000 - 0x18285dfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <ec07a01f70933f629bb77dfa516eac50> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x18285e000 - 0x182861fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <c207a17a12a03d92aaa44fb3d7bb4664> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x182862000 - 0x182869fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <e2f659feb4f33387951c4e76e64be23d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x18286a000 - 0x18287dfff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <291c25bcc2ee33259698edefb7e76a1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x18287e000 - 0x182883fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <db0499e29a383530972aec98f7b20450> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x182884000 - 0x182884fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <d51048b4b2573b18875138004e66b83d> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x182885000 - 0x1828affff libxpc.dylib arm64  <ad6af358f21c3fd9a171d66c6fcc1e0d> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1828b0000 - 0x182ad1fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <32c272e1e9f735aba4c16a17580f13e3> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x182ad2000 - 0x182ae3fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <c402ff63470b34df8634f2078cd151e1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x182ae4000 - 0x182e7cfff CoreFoundation arm64  <733e7542e92b34bd9403762135ad5014> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x182e7d000 - 0x182e8dfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <b7a56e43a852351d8a2dab94c7fc04e6> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x182e8e000 - 0x182e8efff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <6adeca3b70ed33dda70a16353c5ef6ce> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x182e8f000 - 0x182f14fff IOKit arm64  <9e81333d12bd3d06bfdcaa867f2035da> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x182f15000 - 0x182ffefff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <33530216f58333d993d4acb846c63aac> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x182fff000 - 0x18300cfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <35c6ddde076638589f755656ac0058ce> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x18300d000 - 0x183025fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <7d5815f117103d15a67fd30b3375b11b> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x183026000 - 0x183183fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <eac933b033d43444ae182e2d7de6137f> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x183184000 - 0x1831aafff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <9c73d51ef65330e3b29fa4ec81169863> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1831ab000 - 0x183518fff CFNetwork arm64  <fd66a1913ddd34f89f00756cf3147246> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x183519000 - 0x183814fff Foundation arm64  <b0f8df9777ec36008a9f35035b889efd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x183815000 - 0x183903fff Security arm64  <f8097c91a8623fbda138a402b6151ca2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x183904000 - 0x183970fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <13d55604fde63c2e96df89e8d6e84fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x183971000 - 0x1839a7fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <12e6cdcbfa43330da4fa268f1662bf39> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1839a8000 - 0x1839a8fff libapple_crypto.dylib arm64  <26fe924005203d45aee4a14f5cb64434> /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib
0x1839a9000 - 0x1839bffff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <ff88135792b639679509b309f0c0cad9> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x1839c0000 - 0x1839e9fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <957aea53942d3afc91420044f6ae5112> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1839ea000 - 0x183a9bfff libboringssl.dylib arm64  <3c4640e6332d3b44a79759034630ce2a> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x183a9c000 - 0x183ab3fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <c2287d06413f32c2aee0e6c3313d98c7> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x183ab4000 - 0x183ab5fff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <503fb7729cbe382ea1e0a315e7bd87ba> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x183ab6000 - 0x183ab7fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <11d94ede5ab1300a820d96e3374f53fa> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x183ab8000 - 0x183b8bfff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <ba7d2d20eb3a32ac802209e5f7008280> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x183b8c000 - 0x183bbefff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <419a8dd2325a326c81b4b02d849ce562> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x183bbf000 - 0x183bf3fff libusrtcp.dylib arm64  <227ec64866e53676828e76f89c1e4928> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x183bf4000 - 0x183bfdfff IOSurface arm64  <121f7f9d94d63afb8974ca4b14aadbbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x183bfe000 - 0x183ca3fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <05ecdd31f9573a069c0e8b3d610bbc3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x183ca4000 - 0x183fd3fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <3e55f73c8a4c329d8bb7f5e58ed687c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x183fd4000 - 0x184240fff vImage arm64  <7fabce5d1fe83c38aa998440146eb09b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x184241000 - 0x184252fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <88335b280db13b3d812ee89998bc363c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x184253000 - 0x184277fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <20da313fe2343db189a04c72928eb120> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x184278000 - 0x1842a2fff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <19481dd658fb3f949cc1874250cfead5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x1842a3000 - 0x1842b8fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <0f6e8d5a7dd8384ebb8a873c2caa7ad7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1842b9000 - 0x1842bdfff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <124a57c41e3e3956b46e10d49ddf8fe1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x1842be000 - 0x184314fff libSparse.dylib arm64  <c7def66b4a4c3f29b55fcbdcf881e3f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x184315000 - 0x18438dfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <4bf846f47a0e309db93bbbc791720463> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x18438e000 - 0x18438efff vecLib arm64  <86cdd48d842334dd831b1fc0e2b0270f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18438f000 - 0x18438ffff Accelerate arm64  <01d515c3376c332799f14694934ed70b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x184390000 - 0x1843a5fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <b1a3a8c4b3a6301da874dc2af4a50920> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x1843a6000 - 0x1848eafff CoreGraphics arm64  <84200292e2373b96bde75a022c9eeacf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1848eb000 - 0x1848f0fff IOAccelerator arm64  <e66452fc19ef3af29dac52b16e6cb128> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x1848f1000 - 0x1848f6fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <ac1882646b0c3cccb69dfc5246995396> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1848f7000 - 0x184991fff Metal arm64  <ef4fbbbcfa2b38928f3c8ec471c8cde6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x184992000 - 0x1849a5fff GraphicsServices arm64  <60c9cc9a0df43872a837f0ddb03140a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1849a6000 - 0x184afefff MobileCoreServices arm64  <dcdc67868d5a370185e0242a11a54054> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x184aff000 - 0x184b01fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <cf8349e45ac1355386a2d94794f075e4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x184b02000 - 0x184b43fff AppleJPEG arm64  <9ee4b3efde073642af80e42915e2f46c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x184b44000 - 0x1850f4fff ImageIO arm64  <ab5dbbc48a64389487f5572f13867857> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1850f5000 - 0x185159fff BaseBoard arm64  <763fe7d346a337e68e1b067d7359b9f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18515a000 - 0x185171fff AssertionServices arm64  <eac3dcdc35103304b3dc72ce0c8a0a07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x185172000 - 0x18517afff CorePhoneNumbers arm64  <d4693a21c4e83fb09a52ddb833dc793c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePhoneNumbers.framework/CorePhoneNumbers
0x18517b000 - 0x1851bffff AppSupport arm64  <8f2f75f2c4853c7e8e7d9739e12d45cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1851c0000 - 0x1851d8fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <18930e85456c3eb39fe19a4fe0a7d171> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x1851d9000 - 0x1851defff AggregateDictionary arm64  <95f98162fc7836268686104aabee8c12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1851df000 - 0x185260fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <0d366024d6da340a93979ccdec97be29> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x185261000 - 0x185280fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <9bf97e1248b13b959d7a10a0dc8bcaf7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x185281000 - 0x1852acfff MobileKeyBag arm64  <f7fe398063d1384291d2c0f09c64e9e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1852ad000 - 0x1852e1fff BackBoardServices arm64  <6c304c21d68037e9b0646f0deb25ca58> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1852e2000 - 0x18533dfff FrontBoardServices arm64  <6fb061c48f653be48d29f133e1cda578> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18533e000 - 0x18537afff SpringBoardServices arm64  <21b76097326c3a008eed2a77084a3f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x18537b000 - 0x185389fff PowerLog arm64  <b88d155999433dfb9850b7159809529e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x18538a000 - 0x1853a7fff CommonUtilities arm64  <c93c41c50d3f3f48865808dbc37f3b8a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1853a8000 - 0x1853b3fff liblockdown.dylib arm64
...Exceeds character limit of SO. I truncated.
```

Comment: Have you tried an `obj-c` poc equivalent to compare the behavior?

Comment: Yes, same thing. I actually found the issue in `obj-c`. I just converted syntax to Swift to double-check.